# Rake task breaks my Ruby... Bad Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rvm

I'm trying to run a rake task locally and I'm getting a strange error.

```
$ rake alert_notification  --trace
** Invoke alert_notification (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute alert_notification
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake(65399,0x7fff73799960) malloc: *** error for object 0x8: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Oddly enough, I'm not using the gemset given (@globaL).  When I run
    $ rvm gemset list

It shows the correct gemset.

As far as I can tell, this doesn't affect how the rest of my rails app works.  Though I'm not completely certain.

And advice on how I can fix this?

Comment: is there any .rvmrc file in rails dir?

Comment: There's an .rvmrc file in the root directory of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow in the process of we-writing the rake task, this problem has entirely vanished.  So I guess the answer to this post would be "Write valid rake tasks."

Answer (score 1):

just guessing, it looks like you compiled ruby with clang on OSX, there are two ways to get proper compiler for ruby: osx-gcc-installer and:

```
rvm get head
rvm requirements # read the part on homebrew apple gcc42
```

after getting proper compiler you need to reinstall ruby:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

as for the `@global` gemset - it's inherited by all gemsets in given ruby including the default gemset (without any `@...`).